# C# - json is not enumerable

Tags: c#, json

I am fetching json data that is apparently not enumerable. My json class looks like this:

```
public class Bids
{      
    public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> bids { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> asks { get; set; }
}
```

Fetching data:

```
var depth = w.DownloadString("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=20");
                   var book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bids>(depth);
```

And now I want to loop through 'book' and get the bids. How do I do that in a List>?

Edit;
With @TheGeneral's help I managed to get this out.

```
6537.76000000
0.34799400
[]
```

With this loop

```
foreach (var bid in book.bids){
     foreach (var item in bid)
          Console.WriteLine(item);
```

How do I get only the first value?

Comment: Hi, could you share what the array looks like with a couple of items in it ?

Comment: When I console.write(book) it only says BinanceBot.Bids. If you are asking what the json looks like it's here https://api.binance.com/api/v1/depth?symbol=BTCUSDT&limit=20

Comment: Also why is that tagged C# and java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var book = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bids>(depth);

foreach(var bid in book.Bids)
   foreach(var item in bid)
      // blah

foreach(var ask in book.Ask)
   foreach(var item in ask)
      // blah
```

Also, `object` should probably be `double`

```
public List<List<double>> bids { get; set; }
public List<List<double>> asks { get; set; }
```

> How do I get only the first value?

```
Console.WriteLine(book.Ask.First().First());
```

**Update**

```
foreach(var ask in book.Ask)
   Console.WriteLine(ask.First())
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm almost there with this. I edited the OP with the log.

Comment: Thank you. What's weird is that this only writes out the same value over and over, despite iterating through the list.

Comment: @J.Doe what do you want, to write the first of all bids and asks??

Comment: With your first solution I'm getting an array of these [6537.76000000
0.34799400
[], [6545.76000000
0.34793300
[] ] ]. But every bid in the book should have different values, like 6537, 6542 etc. But I'm only getting the same value over and over in the loop, it doesn't move on to the next object and prints it values.

Comment: @J.Doe try that